# didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I've been trying to implement the fetch completion block with no luck. Whenever I send an APN, xcode still complains that it's not implemented. Here's my code

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    println("2. User Data", userInfo)

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)

}
```

and the warning I am getting in the xcode console is this

```
Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.
```

Not sure if I am implementing the right syntax here

Comment: Remove the println or change it to a NSLog, then try again. If that does not work, then wrap the completionHandler in a dispatch block and submit it to some background queue (not the main thread), so it is called AFTER this method returns.

Comment: @DavidH I didn't see the warning anymore when I replaced the `println` with `NSLog`. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the println or change it to a NSLog, then try again. Most likely the problem is caused because this method is coming to you in the background and not on the main thread. println is much simpler than NSLog, which is thread-safe and been hardened for years and years.

Comment: Thanks David. That piece of info is not obvious for the new iOS developers.

Comment: I actually took a guess - I use this method all the time but never saw that error. Lots of complaints about println because it is not thread save. If you search around on SO you will see many people are wrapping println in their own wrapper so it gets output on the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

I had an exact same issue but a totally different solution. The problem of mine is I imported `Intercom` so people can chat in-app, and seems like it intercepts the notifications and the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` never got called in my `AppDelegate`.

I can finally stop banging my head against the wall, hope this can save someone's time.

Comment: A long shot since this is 4 years ago, but I have the same issue since I added Intercom to the app, but I can't get manual push notifications to work (adding IntercomAutoIntegratePushNotifications NO to Info.plist and all that); how did you fix this in the end?

Comment: Again, did you manage so solve this part with intercom notifications ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but replacing `println` with `NSLog` solved the issue.